# Delphi send json + file

Tags: json, file, delphi, post

I am new to delphi and I need to send json string plus some additional files via single http post method, how should I go about this? I can with a solution that works, but since I am using TIdHTTP class the sent json test breaks, and becomes unusable, how should I go about this problem?

```
// Keiciam failu pavadinimus
if form1.ComboBox10.ItemIndex > 0 then
CopyFile(Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\Automatictmp.pdf'), Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\auto_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf'), true);
CopyFile(Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\vistmp.pdf'), Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\full_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf'), true);
CopyFile(Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\tmp.pdf'), Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\tech_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf'), true);
CopyFile(Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\' + uniquetmpfile + '.ini'), Pchar(form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\vmss_' + OfferNumber + extension), true);
try
if form1.ComboBox10.ItemIndex > 0 then
filaspdf.AddFile('Automatic', form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\auto_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf', 'multipart/form-data');
filaspdf.AddFile('AllFile', form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\full_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf', 'multipart/form-data');
filaspdf.AddFile('UserFile', form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\tech_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf', 'multipart/form-data');
filaspdf.AddFile('MainFile', form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\vmss_' + OfferNumber + extension, 'multipart/form-data');
filaspdf.AddFormField('JSON',IvestiniaiJSON);
finally
IdHTTP.Post('http://prgcc.salda.lt/ventmaster_input', filaspdf); // Siunciam i WEB;
end;
filaspdf.Free;
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you read any of the tons of Indy tutorials? why don't you just try `var server: TIdHttp;  Server.Post('http://www.example.com/page.php',parameters,response);`

Comment: now, could you please post the errors you get?

Comment: no errors, the data just breaks, I can;t use php json_decode function as it states, that I am trying to decode and array but I am not, the data example after post: {"Supply":[{"2":["Maintenance side","Right"],"1":["Press. to system (P=^M
a)","300"],"0":["Air volume (m3\/h)","10000"]}],"6":["Type","Supply AH=^M, note "=^M" symbols, they shouldn't be there, their are the ones breaking the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `AddFormField()` encodes string data using MIME's `quoted-printable` transfer format.  Some servers do not support that.  You can disable it by setting the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property if needed:

```
filaspdf.AddFormField('JSON',IvestiniaiJSON).ContentTransfer := '';
```

Note that the default content type for `AddFormField()` is `text/plain`.  The correct content type for JSON is `application/json` instead:

```
with filaspdf.AddFormField('JSON',IvestiniaiJSON) do
begin
  ContentType := 'application/json';
  Charset := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '';
end;
```

Some servers will not accept a content type specified on a text field at all.  You can disable the content type if needed:

```
with filaspdf.AddFormField('JSON',IvestiniaiJSON) do
begin
  ContentType := ' '; // note the space character
  ContentTransfer := '';
end;
```

The whitespace is needed because the content type will be set to `application/octet-stream` if you specify a blank string, but will be set to nothing if the property setter parses an empty string.

With that said, you are specifying the wrong content type when calling `AddFile()`.  `multipart/form-data` is not a valid content type, it is a disposition instead, and `TIdMultipartFormDtaStream` handles that internally for you.  You need to specify the correct content type for the files themselves:

```
filaspdf.AddFile('Automatic', form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\auto_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf', 'application/pdf');
```

Or let `AddFile()` determine the content type for you based on the file extension:

```
filaspdf.AddFile('Automatic', form1.appdatadirStr + 'temp\auto_' + OfferNumber + '.pdf');
```